# How do I construct the cake when using Scalaxb to connect to a SOAP service?

Tags: scalaxb

I've read the documentation, but what I need to know is:

I'm not using a fictitious stock quote service (with an imaginary wsdl file). I'm using a different service with a different name.

Where, among the thousands and thousands of lines of code that have been generated, will I find the Scala trait(s) that I need to put together that correspond to this line in the documentation's example:

```
val service = (new stockquote.StockQuoteSoap12Bindings with scalaxb.SoapClients with scalaxb.DispatchHttpClients {}).service
```

Now, you might be thinking "Why not just search for Soap12Bindings in the generated code"? Good idea - but that turns up 0 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the documentation is outdated, or too specific. (The documentation is also internally inconsistent *and* inconsistent with the actual filenames output with scalaxb.)

First, search for `SoapBindings` instead of `Soap12Bindings` to find the service-specific trait (the first trait).

Then, instead of `scalaxb.SoapClients`, use `scalaxb.Soap11Clients`.